# JSON parse and single quote

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have JSON data passed by PHP and I need to parse it in Javascript.

```
item = JSON.parse('<?=json_encode($item_localized);?>');
```

Some trouble. I have string in $item_localized which contains single quote. [Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) says it valid json. Because I use `'<?=json_encode($item_localized);?>'` - I receive message Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. I cannot use double quotes. I tried replace single quotes with **\'** but it's not working.

Comment: What are you doing here? JSON is for javascript, and you are trying to parse PHP code? Is this inside PHP file or?

Comment: Inside PHP file. json_encode returns valid JSON string and javascript parse data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode` will generate a JSON text.

`JSON.parse` needs to receive a *string* containing a JSON text.

You do need to quote the string, but you can't *simply* place `'` around it because that won't escape any characters in the string that have special meaning in a string literal (like other `'` characters).

If you put a string into `json_encode` then you will get out a JSON text consisting of a string representation of another JSON text. Since JSON is a JS subjet, that string will be JS safe:

```
item = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode(json_encode($item_localized)); ?>);
```

---

This is, however, silly. Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript, you can just use it directly as a JavaScript literal.

```
item = <?php echo json_encode($item_localized); ?>;
```

Comment: It *should* work. What does the generated JS look like? How are you determining that it isn't working?

Comment: "This is, however, silly. Since JSON is a subset" ...and you might want to limit that code snippet to that specific subset (and make it a string instead of a code snippet). Might be, depends on the context...

Answer (score 1):

What about `item = <?=json_encode($item_localized);?>;`?